# Bug in reputation counter.

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, user-interface

Earlier today I downvoted an answer which has a cost of 1 reputation point. Later I retracted my downvote which caused the missing point to return.

In between I also capped out at 245 points (votes+3 accepted answers). After un-downvoting my reputation showed **246** points. I checked [the reputation log](https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation) which agreed that this is preposterous and I ran a re-calculation.

The top page counter was corrected but the profile [reputation tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/622/asaf-karagila?tab=reputation) refuses to cooperate with this action.

Comment: Upvoted, since apparently even 1 point matters a whole lot :)

Comment: I am **really** confused about whoever downvoted a bug report. Bugs should be fixed, regardless to how serious they are. If not fixed then they should at least be known.

Comment: I almost did, just to "bug" you, but figured that an upvote with a comment would suffice :D

Comment: So the thing to do when you hit the cap is immediately downvote and un-downvote a few thousand answers. How cool is that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This rare case is corrected nightly, and happened last night.  The check for the reversal just isn't worth it (it's negative 99.9999% of the time), so we clean up at night for these crazy rare cases.

Comment: Just for the fun of it I am going to game this bug every now and then! :-)